# Essentially solving a linear equation in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linear-programming

I hope someone can help.

Essentially I have a table which contains fixed size data bundles such as: 50gb, 100gb, 250gb and 1000gb. There are more bundles than this but this is to show examples.

[image: Table with bundles]

Essentially I want to create something where I pass it a number such as 1250gb and it will give me a list of which bundle sizes make up this 1250gb bundle from the table mentioned above.

[image: Desired Result]

How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Explain what you mean by "spit out" as well.

Comment: So you define blocks (bundles) of fixed sizes (50, 100, 250, 1000) and want SQL to return the _minimum_ required blocks to fill a target size (1250)? This will not be easy and SQL might not be the best tool for this. Working with the sample data: 1250 = 1000 + 250 (easy), 1500 = 1000 + 250 + 250 (less easy), etc. Explaining this to a computer (SQL) in an algorithm is difficult, these are called [subset sum problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which classify as NP-complete problems. These are notoriously hard for computers...

Comment: Unless you can add certain restrictions to the solution (i.e. a bundle cannot appear more than once in the result) you are looking for some form of brute force algortihm by calculating all combinations below the target size.

Comment: @Sander thanks for the message. You clearly understand what I desire. Unfortunately I cant add a restriction such as the one you mentioned seeing as some bundles can only be constructed by duplicates. 

I know in excel there is something called solver which could essentially work this out for you. Is there nothing similar in SQL?

Comment: There is not out-of-the-box function that you can call for this in T-SQL. You will have to write the query/algorithm/function/procedure yourself.

Comment: @Sander Isn't this just a bin-packing alogrithm?

Comment: @Charlieface, I could be wrong, but [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) is NP-hard when there are multiple bins. Here we have only 1 target size / bin. Another difference is that we do not have a finite number of items to bin, but an infinite number of items (bundles can be repeated).

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a restriction to this subset sum problem, namely that we are looking for the *minimal* required bundles. This allows us to start looking from the biggest to the smallest bundle under the target size (just like handing back cash change, you start from the largest note and work your way down to the smallest coin).

**Sample data**

Added an extra bundle with size `2000` for demonstration purposes.

```
create table bundles
(
  sizeGB int
);

insert into bundles (sizeGB) values
(50),
(100),
(250),
(1000),
(2000);
```

**Solution**

1. Set target size `@targetGB = 1550` to have an example with repeated bundles
   and excluding bundles that are too big.
2. Define an initial value `@sumGB = 0` to increment as we go.
3. Select the biggest bundle `@sumPartGB` that we can add to `@sumGB`
   and stay within the `@targetGB` size limit.
4. Store that part of the sum in a result table `@result`.
5. Increment `@sumGB` with the selected bundle.
6. Repeat as long as `@sumGB < @targetGB`.

In code:

```
declare @targetGB int = 1550;
declare @sumGB    int = 0;

declare @result table
(
  sizeGB int
);

while @sumGB < @targetGB
begin
  declare @sumPartGB int;

  select top 1 @sumPartGB = b.sizeGB
  from bundles b
  where b.sizeGB + @sumGB <= @targetGB
  order by b.sizeGB desc;
  
  insert into @result (sizeGB) values (@sumPartGB);
  set @sumGB += @sumPartGB;
end

select r.sizeGB as sumParts
from @result r
order by r.sizeGB desc;
```

**Result**

```
sumParts
--------
    1000
     250
     250
      50
```

---

Calling this algorithm could be done through a table-valued function (= function that returns a table). How you store or wrap this algorithm ultimately depends on your application.

**Define function**

```
create function getBundles(@targetGB int)
returns @result table (sizeGB int)
as
begin
  declare @sumGB int = 0;
  
  while @sumGB < @targetGB
  begin
    declare @sumPartGB int;
  
    select top 1 @sumPartGB = b.sizeGB
    from bundles b
    where b.sizeGB + @sumGB <= @targetGB
    order by b.sizeGB desc;
    
    insert into @result (sizeGB) values (@sumPartGB);
    set @sumGB += @sumPartGB;
  end
  
  return;
end;
```

**Call function**

```
select r.sizeGB as sumParts
from getBundles(1550) r
order by r.sizeGB desc;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c88d66ed6cadefc852c34960cc6ec8d4) to see everything in action.

Comment: This works as long as the target size is exactly divisible by the bundles available.  Otherwise it repeats the last chosen bundle even if it's bigger than necessary.  I've altered it slightly so that if it's not exactly divisible then it picks the lowest bundle as the final bundle.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28357ab6cfc930d0390c49f8a0f31d7a

This assumes you want a combination of bundles that is always greater than or equal to your target.

Comment: Good point, I did not consider target sizes that cannot be exactly matched with the given bundles.

Comment: @Sander you are a legend. This is amazing and makes sense. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Glad this works for you. Make sure to check Bee_Rii's edit above if you are dealing with target sizes that cannot be matched exactly! If this completes your question then you could formally "accept" the solution as the answer. That way the question is removed from the big pile of unanswered questions.